# is there any function in c++ to check whether a file given in a specific path is a script(.sh) file or not

Tags: c++, unix

there is .sh file in one of the directories
for eg:  path = /opt/WD/CD/SCD/temp.sh

is there any function is c++ to check whether file in that location(path) is a script(.sh) file or not

```
bool ValidCommand(const string & path)
{
bool return = true;

    {
    if (!access(path.c_str(),X_OK))
    {
        return = true;
    }
    else
        return = false;
 }
```

path = /opt/WD/CD/SCD/temp.sh

access is not working for me:(

Comment: You want to check the filename, or the file contents?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at

- stat  -- to check the executable bit
- [libmagic](http://linux.die.net/man/3/libmagic) -- to detect file type from (a.o.) the hash-bang line

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `stat` does what you need, otherwise you can look at the source for `file` and see how it does it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [stat](http://fuse4bsd.creo.hu/localcgi/man-cgi.cgi?lstat+2). If it failed (returned -1), the file doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Just how precise do you want it.  It's fairly straightforward to read
the directory and look for filenames ending in `.sh`.
(`boost::filesystem` has everything you need for that.)  But of course,
I could name my C++ headers `file.sh` if I wanted (and was a bit
perverse).  A considerably more accurate test would involve reading the
start of the file: if the first two bytes are `"#!"`, it's probably a
script of some sort, and if the first line matches
`"#!\\s*(?:/usr)?/bin/sh/[a-z]*sh"`, then you're almost sure it's a shell
script.  Drop the `[a-z]*`, and it's a Bourne or a Posix shell script.